# How to display all selected options using multiple bootstrap-select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, bootstrap-select

I am using silviomoreto bootstrap-select. Here is the link with documentation http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ On few select options I am using multiple select and i have next problem.

If there is more options selected, they don't fit into select input. Like this ([screenshot example](http://screencast.com/t/sIslTKaGU))  . Is there any way that with every new selected option that input box expands the height and display everything that user selected? Also i tried to change css

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .btn .filter-option {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
   color: #333 !important;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   overflow: visible;
   height: 150px;
}
```

but that didn't work neither.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For example like [this](http://screencast.com/t/yOFFLFrXjC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add this line to css of .btn: `white-space: normal;`

```
.bootstrap-select .btn {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Then you must set the correct initial width, padding and stuff. Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions on this page worked for me. I ended up writing some jQuery code to take care of it. Here is it, in case it helps anyone else!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my_select').on('loaded.bs.select hidden.bs.select', function(){ 
    $(this).parent('.bootstrap-select').css('height','auto');
    $(this).next('.btn').css('overflow','hidden').height($(this).next('.btn').find('.filter-option-inner').height()); 
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select id="my_select" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-multiple-separator="<br>">
  <option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
  <option>Value 3</option>
  <option>Value 4</option>
  <option>Value 5</option>
</select>
```

With the result being:

[Multiple Selected Options Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiynI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the multi select instead of the select.

```
   <select class="selectpicker" multiple title='Choose one of the following...'>
         <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
      </select>
```

And if you want the width of your select box to grow with the selections, you could set a dynamic width accordingly to the div.bootstrap-select class.

Comment: I am using multiple as I wrote above. The problem is that it doesn't display everything that user selected. I am wondering if there is a way to display all.

Comment: Can you not just add width:100% to div.bootstrap-select

Comment: yes, that is possible but I need height. If user select like 10 countries for example, that would be too much of width. It wouldn't fit into design. :/